# Execute scalar in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, executescalar

What is the best way to do the equivalent of execute scalar in T-SQL?  In other words, using SQL, how can I get the first column of the first row of the first result set when I call a stored procedure?

**Edit:**
Just to clarify, this is *only* using SQL, no client-side language.  The result set could be something like:

```
Id Description
--------------
1  foo
2  bar
```

I only want "1" in a variable.

The only way I know how to do this is with a temp table (untested, but you get the idea):

```
INSERT #TempTable EXEC MyStoredProcedure

DECLARE @id INT;

SELECT TOP(1) @id = Id FROM #TempTable
```

Comment: +1 I have learned something new because of your question! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're talking about .net client, then you can use SQLCommand.ExecuteScalar.

if not please add an example of how this would look exactly for your case.

EDIT:
you can do this since you provided extra info:

```
-- add 'loopback' linkedserver 
if exists (select * from master..sysservers where srvname = 'loopback')
 exec sp_dropserver 'loopback'
go
exec sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'loopback',
 @srvproduct = N'',
 @provider = N'SQLOLEDB', 
 @datasrc = @@servername
go

select top 1 * @id = id 
from openquery(loopback, 'exec MyStoredProcedure') 
go
```

However this is far from ideal, plus you have to enable ad hoc queries for this to work

Comment: Really a hack which I won't end up using, but it proves that many limitations can be overcome with more indirection. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your temp table solution is probably the only option.

SQL isn't really designed for this

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way I can think of, from what you're asking. =)

<strike>select TOP 1 nameOfFirstColumnReturnedBySP as Column1 from dbo.MyStoredProcedure</strike>

**EDIT #1**

```
-- Assuming this temporary table represents the data structure returned by the SP.
CREATE TABLE @Data (
    Column1 int
    , Column2 nvarchar(10)
)

insert into @Data
    exec dbo.MyStoredProcudure

select TOP 1 Column1
    from @Data
```

Related link: [Stored Procedures: Returning Data](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/stored-procedures-returning-data)

I hope this helps! =)

Comment: you can't do that in sql server. you can't do a select from a stored procedure like that.

Comment: @Mladen Prajdic: You're right! I could have sworn that I have already seen it somewhere. Thanks for your comment, this brought to search further and find a way out.

Comment: well TBH there is a workaround by adding a loopback server to the server itselft and running openquery with exec sproc on it

Comment: if you saw something like that it was probably a user-defined function that returned a table.